# How to do a BLE discovery on a device without GPS chip?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making the kiosk version of an app on a proprietary device that does not have a GPS chip.  That app needs to be connected to a BLE device.

The issue is that I can't do a BLE Discovery without enabling GPS, Google thing.  Asking for the permission brings me to the OS options where I can enable it but `isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)`still returns false.  Not asking for the permission, I can start a discovery but won't detect anything.

Bluetooth detection app NRF Connect works on that device and I can discover BLE devices, so there must be a way, but I am out of ideas.

Comment: BLE != GPS ....

Comment: @MartinZeitler On Android, BLE discovery needs location permissions.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth